# How and where use of !important can create problem for site user?

Tags: css, accessibility

is it not good to use !important in favor of accessibility? How and where use of !important can create problem for site user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!important` CSS rule has no impact on the users' perceived accessibility.

The only argument against `!important` is code readability/maintainability, as such rules tend to make stylesheets more complicated. As you only have two degree of "importance" (with/without `!important`), you might get yourself into a world of pain if you use the rule too often.

That said, you should not avoid `!important` at all costs, but you should consider alternative solutions before adding the rule all around your stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this keyword when i am changing the theme of a site made with a cms like joomla or wordpress to overwrite their styles.

It has nothing to do with accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

It does not create accessibility issues, as `!important` declarations can be overwritten with another `!important` declaration in user's own stylesheet.